# Create two windows in one application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

It might be a simple question, but I don't know where to start the search for the answer. How do I create two individual windows interface in one application using native winapi? Do I put two `CreateWindow()` functions using same `HINSTANCE`? What if I want a login screen windows and the content page such that login screen comes first, and after I press the button, the login screen is destroyed, and the content page appears. How do I do such trick?

I was thinking of using `DestroyWindow` and then `CreateWindow` inside the button click message. However, this would mean the main `while` loop (for translate/dispatch msg) in `WinMain` will exit its loop and cause the whole program to exit. Another way is to pre-create it in `WinMain`, but how would I notify the `WinMain` if the button was clicked and enter the second loop instead of exiting the program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're over-thinking it. To create two windows, call `CreateWindow` twice. It's just that simple.

Calling `DestroyWindow` does not cause your program to exit its message pump. Calling `PostQuitMessage` is what does that. So don't do that.

When the button is clicked, destroy the one window and create the other. There are no tricks. The message pump delivers messages to *all* windows (unless you're doing it wrong by explicitly requesting messages for one window, but you shouldn't do that).

Comment: Oh I thought message function is only specific to window created... Another thing that I still wonder is how do I destroy window? PostQuitMessage and DestroyWindow will not be appropriate in this case

Comment: In what way does DestroyWindow seem like an inappropriate way to destroy a window?

Comment: Oops, sorry for my misunderstanding